# get front end variable with VB.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

How do i pass a javascript value using ajax and get it using vb.net?

i am using a jquery slider that stores the value in a variable that i am unable to access in vb.net. I am looking for any guidance you may have.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var test = 0;
            $(function () {
                $("#slide1, #slide2").slider(
                {
                    range: "max",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        //console.log(ui.values);
                        if (event.target.id == "slide1") {
                            $("#amount1").val("%" + ui.value); //ui is the slider thing (.values[0] is left slider)
                            amt1 = $("#amount1").val();
                        }
                        else if (event.target.id == "slide2") {
                            $("#amount2").val("%" + ui.value);
                            amt2 = $("#amount2").val();
                            //console.log("TEST = " + test);
                        }
                $("#amount1").val("%" + $("#slide1").slider("values", 0));
                $("#amount2").val("%" + $("#slide2").slider("values", 0));
 });
         </script>
```

Comment: add an asp hidden field, before you postback make sure the value you want to store is in the HiddenField, then simply read the HiddenField value in codebehind

Comment: i have added a hiddenfield as you suggested. how do i set the hiddenfield value = amt1's value.

for instance, something like this?
document.medicalprice.hiddenfield1.value = amt11;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of HiddenField on the front end i had to use the following:

```
else if (event.target.id == "slide2") {
                            $("#amount2").val("%" + ui.value);
                            amt2 = $("#amount2").val();
                            //console.log("TEST = " + test);
                            document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = amt2;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per suggest by @zeb, using ASP hidden field is one way.
You can simply set the hidden field value by JQuery

```
$("#HiddenField1").val("YourValue");
```

OR JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "YourValue";
```